# I can't display the results of my web page when running the server after using the chartkick inside my vuejs project (using vue3)

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, vuejs3, chartkick

'Im using `chartkick` inside a vuejs project, so I run the following command: `npm install vue-chartkick chart.js`, and then in the main.js I put the following instructions:

```
import VueChartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import 'chartkick/chart.js'

app.use(VueChartkick)
```

But I can't show the results of my web application when running the server is there any one who knows how to fix that here the code of the  main.js

```
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import VueChartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import 'chartkick/chart.js'

App.use(VueChartkick)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I tried to test this one:

```
<line-chart :data="{'2017-05-13': 2, '2017-05-14': 5}"></line-chart>
```

Comment: Your code mixes Vue 2 and Vue 3 code (even though it's tagged with `vuejs3`). Can you share a link to a Codesandbox that reproduces the problem? Your efforts to create that reproduction might reveal the error and help you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: tony is right. If you are using vue3 you have to import chartkick with this statement: `app.use(Chartkick.use(Chart))` Take a look at the [documentation > Upgrading](https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick#upgrading)